# cron job when Ubuntu is suspended

Tags: ubuntu, cron, suspend

I am using Ubuntu precise. Is there a way to have scheduled cron jobs run even when Ubuntu is suspended? Perhaps some way to automatically wake up the system so a scheduled cron job can proceed and then put it back in suspension?

Comment: Since the BIOS seems to only remember one wakeup at a time, you would need something besides cron, to avoid coordination problems. You need a tool that runs when the system is woken up, executes the background job, waits for it to finish, schedules the next wakeup, and put the system back to sleep. Sounds doable, but I haven't seen it implemented anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarcusJuniusBrutus, the tool you are looking for is called [rtcwake](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake). It allows you to suspend your system and specify a specific wake up time. You can set up a few cronjobs, one to put the machine to sleep using rtwake to turn it on again in time for the second cron.

I found a nice example [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/wake-cron.html):

> If I wanted my machine to sleep overnight, wake for a short
>   maintenance, go to sleep again and wake early in the morning, I would
>   have four crons running. The first, to synchronize the OS clock with
>   UTC (via ntp). The second, to synchronize hardware clock with UTC. The
>   third, to put the machine to sleep every evening, using rtcwake and
>   specify the exact moment when it should wake up later. The fourth cron
>   would run a few minutes after the machine wakes and do whatever needs
>   to be done. After all the tasks are complete, it would sleep the
>   machine once more and make it wake up in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of ubuntu (16.04/16.10) rtcwake is builtin and you can use it via the command "/usr/sbin/rtcwake".